# Firebase dynamic link prefix messed up

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I made an error while creating my firebase dynamic link.

Initially, I created one with prefix: `myapp.com/home` where I had to create one with prefix `myapp.com` and then use this prefix to create the dynamic link (`myapp.com/home`)

When I realized my mistake I deleted `myapp.com/home` prefix and tried to create the correct prefix. However, now I have an error:

```
It looks like you already have content served on this path. Specify a different path prefix to avoid conflicts with existing content.
```

even though I deleted the previous entry and now I don't have any dynamic links. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Please! try the following steps:

1. Open the Console
2. Go to your project
3. Navigate to Firebase Hosting
4. Review the list of deployed files and hosting configurations
5. Make sure that your Dynamic Link path doesn't conflict with any of the existing paths or files